# Angular pagination sorting items

Tags: javascript, angularjs, sorting, pagination

I have managed to implement Angular pagination for a project but I want the most recently created items displayed first.

They all have a value of "created_at" (from a Ruby on Rails API) which is what i'm trying to sort them by.

At the moment it's displaying as follows:
Page 1 - 3, 2, 1
Page 2 - 4, 5, 6
Page 3 - 7

Whereas I need to display as:
Page 1 - 7, 6, 5
Page 2 - 4, 3, 2
Page 3 - 1

HTML:
`<div ng-repeat="post in postsIndex.all  | startFrom: (currentPage - 1) * pageSize | limitTo: pageSize" class="post" >`

app.js:

```
.angular
.module('blog', ['ui.bootstrap'])
.constant('API_URL', 'https://api-example-address.com')
.filter('startFrom', function(){
return function(data, start){
  return data.slice(start);
 };
});
```

And this for my post controller:

```
PostsIndexCtrl.$inject = ['Post', 'filterFilter', '$scope'];
function PostsIndexCtrl(Post, filterFilter, $scope) {
  const vm = this;
  vm.all = Post.query();
  $scope.pageSize = 3;
  $scope.currentPage = 1;
}
```

I can't work out to sort all of the items, rather than just those that show on the page. Is there a way to sort them all before they are loaded to the page in the ng-repeat?

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it! Just a case of changing the "orderBy" to before the startFrom property.

Fixed by using this:

```
  <div ng-repeat="post in postsIndex.all | orderBy:'created_at':true  | startFrom: (currentPage - 1) * pageSize | limitTo: pageSize" class="post" >
```

instead of this:

```
  <div ng-repeat="post in postsIndex.all  | startFrom: (currentPage - 1) * pageSize | limitTo: pageSize | orderBy:'created_at':true" class="post" >
```

Answer (score 0):

Sort the data like so:

```
data.sort(function(a,b){
  // Turn your strings into dates, and then subtract them
  // to get a value that is either negative, positive, or zero.
  return new Date(b.date) - new Date(a.date);
});
```

Comment: Do you mean to add that into the app.js or the post controller? I've tried orderBy: "created_at" but that only works for the items on the page, and not every item in the data.